# Dimension of subspace of $Hom(V,W)$, under kernel condition

Tags: linear-algebra

I need to find the following:

> Let $V,W$ be finite dimensional vector spaces over $\mathbb{F}$, and let $U \subseteq V$ be a subspace of $V$.
>
> $U \neq\{0_V\}, V$
>
> $E = \{T \in Hom(V,W)\ |\  U \subseteq kerT\}$
>
> Find $dimE$

My attempt:

Set $n = dimV,\ m = dimW$

$U \subset V \Rightarrow$ $U$ is finite dimensional, hence we can choose a basis $(u_1,...,u_k)$ to $U$.

Also, there exist vectors $(v_1,...,v_{l})$ such that $(u_1,...,u_k,v_1,...,v_l)$ is a basis to $V$.

Now we know that $V = U \bigoplus Span(v_1,...,v_l) = L$, hence $dimL = n - k$.

We know that it's sufficient to define a linear transformation from a finite dimensional space individually by a basis.

So for every $T \in Hom(L,W)$ we can define $T_V:V\rightarrow W$:

$T_V(v) = 
 \begin{cases} 
      0_W & v\in U \\
      T(v) & otherwise \\
   \end{cases}
$

In other words, we can define $\gamma : Hom(L,W) \rightarrow Hom(V,W)$, such that

$\gamma (T) = T_V$

It's clear that $\gamma$ is a linear transformation.

Let $S \in Hom(L,W)$ satisfy that $\gamma (S) = T_{0_V}(\forall v\in V, T_{0_V}(v) = 0_W)$.

By definition of $\gamma \Rightarrow \gamma (S)(v) = 
\begin {cases}
        0_W & v \in U \\
        0_W & otherwise \\
\end {cases}
\Rightarrow S = T_{0_L}
$

And therefore, $ker(\gamma) = \{T_{0_L}\} \Rightarrow \gamma$ is one-to-one.

By definition of $\gamma$, $E = Im(\gamma)$, and $\gamma$ is one-to-one, and therefore

$dimE = dim(Hom(L,W)) = (n-k)*m$

Is this correct? How rigorous is this proof?

Is there a way to prove it using an isomorphism between $Hom(V,W)$ and $M_{m\times n}(\mathbb{F})$?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

The linear maps $T\colon V\to W$ such that $U\subseteq\ker T$ are precisely those which factor through $V/U$. So $E$ is isomorphic to $\operatorname{Hom}(V/U,W)$.

Your argument is good, however. When you have extended a basis of $U$ to a basis of $V$, you have essentially computed a complement $U'$ of $U$ in $V$, so $V=U\oplus U'$. A linear map $T\colon V\to W$ such that $U\subseteq \ker T$ is precisely determined by a linear map $T'\colon U'\to W$. So $\dim E=(\dim V-\dim U)\cdot\dim W$: any linear map $T'\colon U'\to W$ can be uniquely extended to a linear map $T\colon V\to W$ with $U\subseteq \ker T$.

Note that the hypothesis that $U\ne\{0\}$ and $U\ne V$ is irrelevant.